# How to size 3 buttons responsively without media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-email, email-templates

I have 3 buttons in a row in an email. When this is viewed on a mobile screen, they are squashed per the picture below.

[image: Squashed output on a narrow screen]

Can someone please help with how I can size these to be read in a "normal" manner on a mobile screen without media queries (this is an email, so all my styling is in-line).

Any solution is fine - as long as the wording doesn't appear to be squashed.

```html
<tbody style="padding-top:10px">
  <tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
    <td valign="top" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse;padding:5px 0">

      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:33px 2px">
        <tbody>
          <tr style="border-collapse:collapse">
            <td bgcolor="#fae231" valign="top" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse;padding:13px 17px;border-radius:8px;background-color:#fae231">
              <a href="https://fluf.io/profile/?testaccountgt/orders/view-order/7501" style="line-height:1.5;text-decoration:none;word-break:break-word;font-weight:500;display:block;font-family:'Fira Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#161616" target="_blank"
                data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://fluf.io/profile/?testaccountgt/orders/view-order/7501&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1646256195425000&amp;usg=AOvVaw3u-T-1Gq8L6jxeAo388tcD">View order</a>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#fae231" valign="top" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse;padding:13px 17px;border-radius:8px;background-color:#fae231">
              <a style="line-height:1.5;text-decoration:none;word-break:break-word;font-weight:500;display:block;font-family:'Fira Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#161616">Track order</a>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#fae231" valign="top" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse;padding:13px 17px;border-radius:8px;background-color:#fae231">
              <a href="https://fluf.io/outlets//reviews/" style="line-height:1.5;text-decoration:none;word-break:break-word;font-weight:500;display:block;font-family:'Fira Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#161616" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://fluf.io/outlets//reviews/&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1646256195425000&amp;usg=AOvVaw2n8CPAJtw95Aum6KO_PqNR">Submit a Review</a>
            </td>

          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

[Code as Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pejz608L/)

Comment: Can we have your CSS?

Comment: @Ethan as you see in the question description it uses `inline-style`. An email (as mentioned in the description) has barely support for CSS.

Comment: @tacoshy my bad I didn't see it.

Comment: If there's not enough space, environments like iOS will add their own word-breaking code in there to make it fit. I don't think you can override it. What about making it stack for mobile, would that be acceptable?

Comment: Hey everyone (@ethan / @tacoshy / @Nathan), appreciate the inputs here.
Nathan, what do you mean by making it stack for mobile? Like the buttons overlapping over each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no responsive way if you use a table as the tables will not break into elss columns if there is not enough width. The one thing you can do is to change `display:block;` to `display:inline-block`. Then use `white-space: nowrap` to prevent a linebreak within the button:

```html
<a href="https://fluf.io/profile/?testaccountgt/orders/view-order/7501" style="line-height:1.5;text-decoration:none;word-break:break-word;font-weight:500;display:inline-block;font-family:'Fira Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#161616;padding:13px 17px;border-radius:8px;background-color:#fae231;white-space:nowrap;" target="_blank"
  data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://fluf.io/profile/?testaccountgt/orders/view-order/7501&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1646256195425000&amp;usg=AOvVaw3u-T-1Gq8L6jxeAo388tcD">View order</a>

<a style="line-height:1.5;text-decoration:none;word-break:break-word;font-weight:500;display:inline-block;font-family:'Fira Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#161616;padding:13px 17px;border-radius:8px;background-color:#fae231;white-space:nowrap;">Track order</a>

<a href="https://fluf.io/outlets//reviews/" style="line-height:1.5;text-decoration:none;word-break:break-word;font-weight:500;display:inline-block;font-family:'Fira Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;color:#161616;padding:13px 17px;border-radius:8px;background-color:#fae231;white-space:nowrap;" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://fluf.io/outlets//reviews/&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1646256195425000&amp;usg=AOvVaw2n8CPAJtw95Aum6KO_PqNR">Submit a Review</a>
```

Comment: THis is not factually true. You can make a table layout stackable (1 column, 3 rows on mobile; 3 columns, 1 row on desktop). Just google responsive html email

Comment: Thanks @tacoshy - i found this helpful

Answer (score 0):

followed @Nathan's advice in the end and chose to stack the table using display:table-row on the table data elements.

Was unsure however how to toggle it such that desktop is 1 row and mobile is 3 (in the absence of media queries - given again, it's an email). Have just gone for 3 rows and fine with that.